# Pointer to function of derived class withing parent class

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, derived-class, base-class

Currently I'm learning Win32 and C++ and I finished my first application. Now I want to translate the code from functional style to OOP. Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

class BaseWindow {
    public:
    BaseWindow ();
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) abstract;
    bool Register ();
};

BaseWindow::BaseWindow () {}

bool BaseWindow::Register () {
    WNDCLASSEXW wnd = {0};
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = &BaseWindow::WndProc;    // Error | How to point to the derived class's WndProc
    // Some other properties
    return RegisterClassExW(&wnd) != NULL;
}



class MainWindow : BaseWindow {
    using BaseWindow::Register;

    public:
    MainWindow();
    bool Register ();
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

MainWindow::MainWindow () : BaseWindow () {}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // Handling messages
}
```

How to bind the derived class's `WndProc` to the parent class's `wnd.lpfnWndProc` in `BaseWindow::Register`?

Comment: Was there a question? And your registered `WndProc` needs to be `static` or a stand-alone external function friended to the class. You cannot use a simple member function as a registered wndproc callback.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. Is there no way to bind the `lpfnWndProc` to a class's member?

Comment: There is, but it isn't necessarily trivial (at least not to a beginner). One way to do it [can be seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382174/why-cant-i-bind-to-winproc/17634960#17634960). Generally it involves providing your object pointer as part of the windows api `CreateWindow` creation parameters, then storing that pointer within the window-extra-bytes of the window instance for future usage when dispatching messages. Read that link. Its not (imho) ideal, but it is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a non-static class method as a window procedure callback. The parameter list is not compatible due to the hidden `this` pointer.  What you have to do instead is:

1. In `BaseWindow`, define a static method as the actual message callback registered with `RegisterClassEx()`, and then define a separate virtual method for processing messages.  Have the `BaseWindow` implementation of the virtual method call `DefWindowProc()`, and descendants that override the virtual method need to call the base method for unhandled messages.
2. Pass the object's `this` pointer as the `lpCreateParam` of `CreateWindow/Ex()`.
3. In the `WM_NCCREATE` message handler, retrieve the `lpCreateParam` value from the message and assign it to the HWND using either `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_USERDATA)` or `SetProp()`, then type-cast the value to a `BaseWindow*` pointer and use it to call the virtual method.
4. For subsequent messages, use `GetWindowLongPtr(GWL_USERDATA)` or `GetProp()` to retrieve the `BaseWindow*` pointer from the HWND and use it to call the virtual method.